# What is the better way to structure components' props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm now testing some Material-UI components and can't understand 1 moment. For example, in List component. Why do they use syntax like this?

```html
<List component="nav">
  <ListItem
    button
    selected={selectedIndex === 0}
    onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
  >
    <ListItemIcon>
      <InboxIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

it seems to me that you can just use this approach:

```html
<List component="nav"
  items=[
    {
      icon: 'inbox',
      text: 'Inbox',
      onClick: () => handleListItemClick()
    }
  ]
/>
```

Оr you can also use render props.
What makes their approach more convenient? after all, they clearly chose it for some reason

Comment: I see the first one more explicit, and more easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with their style, the example seems simple to follow maybe for presentation purposes. For real use application usage you may want to do your array style example.